# Own mapMaybe does not parse

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, option-type

So I have the following type annotation in Haskell:

```
mapMaybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

And it is defined as follows:

```
mapMaybe _ Nothing = Nothing
mapMaybe f (Just x) = Just (head (map f [x]))
```

Now, in `main`, when I try `print (mapMaybe length Nothing)`, I get

[image: Incorrect]

On the other hand, the following works:

```
print (mapMaybe length (Just "abc"))
```

... and prints `Just 3`.

Comment: `Nothing` has a type `Maybe a`, you cannot apply `length` to an `a` because it is not known to be a list. OTOH `Just "abc"` has type `Maybe [Char]`.

Comment: BTW `head (map f [x])` is a funny way to spell `f x`, and your `mapMaybe` is just `fmap`. `Data.Maybe` has an entirely different `mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]`.

Comment: @n.m. Please bear with me. Not only Haskell is new to me, the entire functional programming paradigm is something I haven’t done previously.

Comment: You want to specify the type of `Nothing` e.g. `print (mapMaybe length (Nothing :: Maybe [a]))`.

Comment: Note that if you evaluate `print (mapMaybe length Nothing)` at the GHCi prompt, it works just fine. GHCi has relaxed typing rules to help with cases like this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)